# Flashing new radio to my Desire HD

Tags: rom-flashing, htc-desire-hd, radio-firmware

Last week, I decided to flash a custom ROM to my 2 year old Desire HD. I used the hack kit (AAHK) and flashed Jellytime R30. Everything is great... except for the non-existent GPS.

After looking around, I've managed to [tracked the issue](https://code.google.com/p/jellytime/issues/detail?id=223) down to an incompatible/outdated radio on my device. My current baseband version is **12.56.60.25U_26.10.04.03_M**.

According to the ticket, people were able to make the GPS work by flashing a new radio version **12.69.60.29_26.17.14.11_M**. To aid me in flashing a new radio, I read a lot and figured out that [I would need to do the following steps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9891581&postcount=3):

Requirements: S-OFF

- Download the radio file
- Rename it to PD98IMG.zip (this is important!)
- Move the file to your SD-card root (not in any folder)
- Download MD5 Checksum Checker
- Make sure that the MD5 provided with the download link matches with your downloaded file!
  ^ If not performed, you might risk bricking your device!
- If they match, you are ready to go! Power off your device.
- Hold the volume-down and powerbutton simultaneously 
  ^ This will boot you into Fastboot/Bootloader
- You should see a screen with options
- Navigate to Bootloader (if not already in it) and press the powerbutton
- Wait for the flashing process to begin (it does automatically!).
- Reboot your phone and you are done!

So here are my questions:

1. Are the steps I've laid out above correct?
2. Will radio version **12.69.60.29_26.17.14.11_M** work for my device? It's HTC Desire HD bought in the Philippines on May 2010. (According to the thread, this is from an Inspire device)
3. Will this radio work in the Philippines? (I've read that radios are "region" specific. If they are, where can I download a radio for our region?)
4. According to a [user](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=33556153&postcount=4), "flash ENG S-OFF and your device was shipped with Gingerbread you will mess your bootloader and radio won't be the main concern then". I'm currently on S-OFF (via AAHK) and my device was shipped with Froyo (I think). Will this be a problem? (I don't understand what he is saying).

That's all. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You've done your research right, bro. Another recommended way is using the commandline fastboot which can be easily followed-through [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=896597). I'm using the same custom ROM as you are, though, I can't utilize the bootloader interface on the phone as I already cut off the flex of its volume rockers(yields nonbooting issues for me already).
2. It'll work just like it did on mine. Not an official WWE(international) radio, though.
3. The latest WWE applicable is 12.65.xxxx but GPS will not function already when using JellyTime R30(which is based on the latest pull from CM10).
4. Since you already have flashed a custom ROM I believe it's safe to say you don't have to deal with issues regarding S-OFF